Ebay API error: Authorization Code Grant Type "invalid_grant" error, C#
I am trying to get user access token(Authorization Code Grant Type) by using c#.
Unfortunately, it is returning 400(Bad request) error. When I tried the same method for client_credentials, it works successfully.
Error message after running the code;
 System.Net.HttpRequestException has been thrown
"Response status does not indicate success: 400(Bad Request)

Full error message on output;
Status Code: BadRequest
Reason Phrase: Bad Request
Error Content: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"}

My code;
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "...CLIENTID…";
        string clientSecret = "...CLIENTSECRET…";
        string authorizationCode = "v%...";
        string redirectUri = "...REDİRECTURI…";  
        string credentials = $"{clientId}:{clientSecret}";
        string base64Credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials));

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token");

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {base64Credentials}");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", authorizationCode)
            });
            request.Content = content;

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
      
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
}


I follow Ebay's Authorization Code Grant type documentation and expect to have response with access and refresh tokens like that;
  {
    "access_token": "v^1.1#i^1#p^3#r^1...XzMjRV4xMjg0",
    "expires_in": 7200,
    "refresh_token": "v^1.1#i^1#p^3#r^1...zYjRV4xMjg0",
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 47304000,
    "token_type": "User Access Token"
  }

